# How to alter the css of a helper generated div in rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I've been using the mailboxer gem. One of teh views users a helper method to create a title

```
<% page_header "Start Conversation" %>
```

This helper method is defined in application_helper.rb

```
def page_header(text)
    content_for(:page_header) { text.to_s }
  end
```

I am also using the gem bootstrap-sass (latest version)

The html result is

```
<div class="line">&lt;% page_header &quot;Start Conversation&quot; %&gt;
```

I want to reduce the font size of the div rendered by page_header but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `class` option to your [content_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for)

```
def page_header(text)
  content_for(:page_header, text.to_s, class: 'small-font-size')
end
```

Then in your `css` file add

```
div.small-font-size{
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nermin's approach is better, but it's worth mentioning that you can also use the `style` attribute to set specific properties on an element:

```
def page_header(text)
  content_for(:page_header, text.to_s, style: 'font-size: 9px;')
end
```